# How to search files usage in whole project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I pushed a git Hub [project](https://github.com/yangyueyul/KReader) into my android studio.
As you can see in this project it has lots of files consist of java classes, assets and etc.

My problem is that I don't want to search **all project files** to find where asset files especially *style.css* is used.

I also tried **pressing shift twice** but it doesn't give me my desired result.

Is there any to find out where our project files specially assets are used?

**Any help will be appreciated**

Comment: did you try ctrl + shift + f ??

Comment: I can at least think of: right-click on the file -> Find Usages.

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + F` is the global search shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **CTRL+SHIFT+F** for search the particular file in whole project in android studio.